# Select SQL rows with latest date for each Phase and for each Order

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table "Production_Phases_History" which tracks my Order Phases, there is only three phases repeated for each order.
I want to select each latest row by "Date" for each "ID_Phase", for each order.

Sample -

| ID_Phase | ID_Order | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 01/04/2023 |
| 2 | 0001 | 01/04/2023 |
| 3 | 0001 | 01/04/2023 |
| 1 | 0001 | 21/04/2023 |
| 2 | 0001 | 21/04/2023 |
| 3 | 0001 | 21/04/2023 |
| 1 | 0002 | 01/04/2023 |
| 2 | 0002 | 01/04/2023 |
| 3 | 0002 | 01/04/2023 |
| 1 | 0002 | 21/04/2023 |
| 2 | 0002 | 21/04/2023 |
| 3 | 0002 | 21/04/2023 |

The Answer should be

| ID_Phase | ID_Order | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 21/04/2023 |
| 2 | 0001 | 21/04/2023 |
| 3 | 0001 | 21/04/2023 |
| 1 | 0002 | 21/04/2023 |
| 2 | 0002 | 21/04/2023 |
| 3 | 0002 | 21/04/2023 |

I've made a few attempts:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM Production_Phases_History tt
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID_Phase, MAX(Date) AS MaxDateTime
  FROM Production_Phases_History
  GROUP BY ID_Phase) groupedtt 
ON tt.ID_Phase = groupedtt.ID_Phase
WHERE ID_Order = 0001
AND tt.Data = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
ORDER BY ID_Phase
```

But the result is wrong.

Thanks

I want to select each latest row by "Date" for each "ID_Phase", for each order.

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: these no valuid mysql date they hqave the format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL8 you can use window function for that

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
  `ID_Phase`, `ID_Order`, `Date`
  , ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY `ID_Phase`, `ID_Order` ORDER BY  `Date` DESC)rn
  FROM table1)
  SELECT 
 `ID_Phase`, `ID_Order`, `Date`
  FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY  `ID_Order`,`ID_Phase`
```

| ID_Phase | ID_Order | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 2023-04-21 |
| 2 | 0001 | 2023-04-21 |
| 3 | 0001 | 2023-04-21 |
| 1 | 0002 | 2023-04-21 |
| 2 | 0002 | 2023-04-21 |
| 3 | 0002 | 2023-04-21 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Z5W2sdO)

Comment: Would only work if the date field was indeed a date. In which case the sql statement in the question would also have worked...

Comment: @Shadow not it will work also with Varchar dates ,as dates as text can be sorted as he has 01 for days and 04 for month

Comment: No, it will not work as 03/01 would sort higher as 01/03...